# How to resolve TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "types.GenericAlias") to str

Tags: python, error-handling

I faced the following error:

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "types.GenericAlias") to str

What does this error reflect and how can it be resolved?

As far as I remember I was trying to multiply a string with an expression in a variable i which was the iterating variable in the for loop. However I haven't been able to find the specific example again. I had noted the error as I couldn't find any examples for it

Comment: You should post your code, but apparently you were trying to concatenate a str with an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be obvious from the error message. You can't concatenate strings to other objects.

```py
'str1' + 'str2'    # OK
'str1' + MyClass() # TypeError

# But, you can also try to cast an object to str
# In this case Python will try to get a result from __str__ method
# And will fallback to __repr__ if __str__ is not defined
'str1' + str(MyClass()) # OK
```

So, concatenate only strings.